# Error sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis python

Tags: python

I have this error `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 3` when I execute this code :

```
a3 = "e)/ragues"
numbera3 = sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\b{}\b".format(a3), resp))
```

I thinks it's due to the regex and the ")" of a3 variable but I don't know how can I do to do to not have this error..

Thanks,

Comment: Well, either balance the parenthesis or escape the `)`

Comment: What does this statement mean? `a3 = e)/ragues` Did you mean `a3 = "e)/ragues"`?

Comment: sorry a3 = e)/ragues is in fact a3 = "e)/ragues"

Answer (score 0):

if `a3 = "a3 = e)/ragues"`

Then it is being treated as part of the regular expression.
which means `)` is looking for another `(` to balance the expression.

you can use `\(` to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a3 isn't ever meant to have anything regular expression-y in it then:

```
r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(a3))
```

If the goal is to allow a3 to contain regular expression syntax within it, then you'd need to have whatever/whoever is generating a3 make sure it's a valid regex.

Comment: In fact `a3 = e)/ragues` is a3 =  `"e)/ragues" ` it's a string

Comment: @CodingFR -- Not sure if that comment was directed at me or not.  I assumed that you had just missed the quotes.  I'm simply showing you the generic way of escaping something that's going to be embedded as part of regex.  If you're going to pass a variable into a regex (which is what you're doing here) and that variable is a string that the regex is searching for and not additional regex syntax itself, you need to escape that variable.  You use re.escape to do that.